# Algorithm used for Eventhub Round robin

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

If a specific partition is not specified when sending a message to an Event hub I understand that the message is assigned to a partition in a round Robin fashion.

However, for the round Robin, does the Eventhub literally keep a flag of the next partition number to forward to, or is more complex logic used such as taking some hash of the event data and a mod to give the partition number?  If anybody knows the algorithm,please let me know.

We are looking to implement a similar approach for sending messages in batches to know which partition to forward to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eventhub, the round robin uses a simple mod operation:(index of message) % (total number of partitions).

Assume you have 15 messages(indexes are 0-14), and 5 partitions(indexes are 0-4).

Then the first message(index 0) will mod 5(the total number of partitions), like 0%5. it returns 0, so the first message will go to partition number 0.

Then the 2nd message(index 1) will mod 5, like 1%5. it returns 1, so the 2nd message will go to partition number 1.

For other messages, they will follow the algorithm above.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have a cross reference for this? I couldn't find any links concerning this - i got the impression it was a proprietary implementation?